# How to access view path from inherited controller?

Tags: c#, inheritance, view, controller

So I have 2 controllers where one is a master controller. They look a little like this:

```
public class MaterController : ControllerBase
{
}
```

and

```
public class ChildController : MaterController
{
}
```

So my `ChildController` inherits from the `MasterController`.  My MasterController has some views which can be found simply by having this:

```
return this.View("MyViewName");
```

However, when in my `ChildController`, I am unable to access the `MyViewName` without specifying the full file path in the system.  Why is this? and can I do anything so I don't have to specify the full path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do it with the other controller name:

```
return View("/MaterController/MyViewName");
```

Comment: The only way I can seem to get it to work so far is to put the path as:
"~/Views/Master/ViewName.cshtml"
which isn't really what I want to have to do.

Comment: Did you try with the relative path? I will work file like this:
View("../Master/ViewName", model);

Comment: Ok I'll give that another shot.  The guy I'm working with has locked his computer for his dinner break, so I'll let you know if it's worked once he gets back.